# FFMPEG: Stream microphone with 32 channels via RTP

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, merge, channel

I want to stream a microphone with 32 channels (audio interface/mixer) as mono audio via RTP with ffmpeg.

Currently I'm using this:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -v info -i ":${DEVICE}" -map "0:a:0" \
-acodec libopus -ab 48k -ac 1 -ar 48000 \
-f tee "[select=a:f=rtp:ssrc=1111:payload_type=100]rtp://0.0.0.0:49386?rtcpport=59871"
```

And I'm getting the devices with:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f avfoundation -i ""
```

It works fine for devices with a normal count of channels. But for the device with 32 channels I'm getting the following error:

```
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0x7fc6f7d1d340] [SWR @ 0x7fc6fa4f8000] Rematrix is needed between 64 channels and mono but there is not enough information to do it
[auto_resampler_0 @ 0x7fc6f7d1d340] Failed to configure output pad on auto_resampler_0
```

After some tries with channelmap I thing the error starts with 9 channels or more. Is it even possible to merge 32 channels with ffmpeg and send the microphone as mono via RTP?

Comment: the readership on [dsp.se] will be more likely to have experience with this level  of problem. Cross-posting is frowned upon, so do some exploring there, and if it looks to be a good fit, post there and delete this. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself. You can use the pan filter from ffmpeg like:

`-filter_complex "pan=1c|c0=c1+c2+c3+..."`